# Orientation issue in ios8 when setting RootViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode6, orientation, ios8.1

I'm working on an application in which i'm setting the rootViewController as,

```
 if(token){
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIViewController* viewController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                    initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]
                   initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
  }
```

when this piece of code works the orientation is not working properly, the status bar rotates but  the view stays the same.

This works perfectly in iOS7.1 and below but when it runs on iOS8.1 we get this issue.